# Is it possible to make a segue in a case in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

Ive made a Settings Menu programmatically, and it uses enums and cases for the Cell Info.

```
enum SettingsSection: Int, CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible {
    case Social 
    case Communications

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .Social: return "General"
        case .Communications: return "Communication"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem comes when I am trying to make a cell perform a segue.
There is no 'self' in this Swift file. So I made a function in a View Controller, and tried to use that to perform the segue:

```
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .editProfile: return "Edit Profile"
        case .logout:
            SettingsViewController().Logout()
            return "Log Out"
        }
    }
```

And it doesn't give an error until I run the app, and click on the cell, the error that comes is:

```
 Get It Done[8620:987786] Warning: Attempt to present <Get_It_Done.ViewController: 
0x1017af660> on <Get_It_Done.SettingsViewController: 0x1017aed20> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
Optional("Log Out")
```

Here is what Logout() does in SettingsViewController:

```
 public func Logout() {
    let vc = ViewController() //your view controller
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Hard to actually say, partly because your question (to me) is somewhat vague. But I'll give you two pieces of help in two separate comments. First, about segues.... they really belong to IB. You simply *cannot* create *and* execute one in code. But here's the good news - all a segue does is push/pop a view controller in a navigation controllers stack. And that **is** something easily done in code.

Comment: Second, about your error. It indicates there's something wrong with your view hierarchy. Namely, something called `SettingsViewController` is expected to be already in the hierarchy but isn't. Here's where your question makes it hard - so far what you cannot be duplicated. From what you've said - basically that you are trying to "perform a segue" from a Settings menu you've created "programmatically" - I'd recommend setting up a new project and try to do what you want to do (is it move or push/pop from one VC to a second? or present one VC from another?) - but do it without a Settings menu.